# to delete file which starts with ~$ (Word temp file) in windows command line

Tags: svn, batch-file

In a folder I want to delete files which starts with ~$(people committed in SVN and when we checkout we will get all the desktop.in, Thumbs.db & ~$ files). How can I do it in windows command line?

For example:

```
for %G in (desktop.ini, Thumbs.db, ~$*.*) do forfiles /P "d:\mydir" /S /M *%G /C "cmd /c del /F /S /A:H @path"
```

Which is not working for me.

I am able to delete desktop.ini and Thumbs.db. ~$*.* .Don't know how to delete.

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd "d:\mydir" & del /f /s /a /q desktop.ini thumbs.db ~$* & popd
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and all the switches please a bit. Code only is not an answer.